# Properly mocking imported default function with vitest

Tags: mocking, vitest

I have a function which exports with default:

```js
export default async function myFunction(...) {
    ....
    return someData;
}
```

Also a function which I want to test using vitest:

```js
import myFunction from './myFunction';

export default async function functionUnderTest(...) {
    const values = await myFunction();
    ...
    return true;
}
```

How can I properly mock `myFunction` in vitest? ATM my testing code looks like:

```js
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';

import functionUnderTest from '../src/functionUnderTest';

vi.mock('../src/myFunction');

describe('from scratch', async() => {
  const modes = [
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
  ];

  const myFunction = await import('../src/myFunction');

  for (let i = 0; i < modes.length; i += 1) {
    it('should work correctly', async () => {
      myFunction.default = vi.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce([]);
    }
  }
});
```

I couldn't get it work another way but it feels highly undesirable to import `myFunction` in the `describe` block. Also I should "clean up" the mock somewhere.

For cleanup I tried:

```js
  afterEach(() => {
    vi.restoreAllMocks()
  })
```

but I have other mocks I don't want to cleanup.

Solutions I'm looking for:

- Setting up the mock properly in one place and call only `mockResolvedValueOnce` in the `it` block.
- Clean up the mock properly.